# How to create a mailing list in thunderbird directly from a spreadsheet

Tags: thunderbird, import

How can I import a spreadsheet (or csv file) containing a list of e-mail addresses directly to a thunderbird mailing list? I know that I can import the csv file to my address book but then I would have to create manually the mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have imported the CSV file into an address book, I assume the
problem that is left is to create the mailing list in one action,
rather than copying it one-by-one, which is the method described
by most articles.

To add all the contacts in an address book to a mailing list:

- Use the menu *File > New > Mailing List* to create an empty mailing list
- Select the address book so its contents are displayed
- Select the contacts you want to list. To select all of them,
  click on the first contact, and while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> click on the
  last contact.
- Left-click and hold the selected highlighted contacts
- Drag the selected contacts to the left and hover over the mailing list
- Release the mouse button to drop contacts into the mailing list.

Source : [Mozilla How to create and use mailing lists on Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-create-and-use-mailing-lists-thunderbird).